# Long wait after interview

Tags: interviewing

So i had this interview about a month ago.  I think the interview went well, and the job interviewer seemed to be interested in me filling the job position. Towards the end of the interview, i casually asked if there will be another interview and he mentioned 2 weeks time and even gave me the exact date.  Between this interview i attended and the supposedly 2nd interview, he did mentioned he will be traveling. Yes, traveling for 2 weeks

The date of the supposedly 2nd interview have passed by a week and 3 days. The delay could be because he could be busy, he could be off traveling again, he could be this or he could be that.    I have continued applying for other jobs but  i am anxious to know what is my status for the job i had interviewed for.

My question is how can one know the real reason for the delay, from what i have read online, its all guess work / speculative in the justifying the reason(s) for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

> How can one know the real reason for the delay?

The only way you could know the *real* reason for the delay is if the person told you the truth.

---

The answer ends above. Sometimes the answer is just that simple and short, but that doesn't delight everyone, so I will pad it with some <s>fluff</s> additional commentary.

Only the person who told you the interview date would know the real reason for the delay, anything else which anyone else says is pure speculation. You could call him to ask, and hope that you get a truthful response, but I won't bet any money on it.

From my personal experience, "interview will be delayed because interviewer is *travelling*" is a red flag, because it is used as an euphemism for "you did not make it to the next round, but we don't have the heart to tell you. So we will not have any further contact with you, you will eventually get it."

In the somewhat more sinister version, it could be an euphemism for "we consider you good enough, but not great. We would like to shop around for a while, and come back to you if we don't find a better candidate. But we want to make sure you are still around if need be."

Comment: Agree with your answer, disagree with your fluff... Or the interviewer is actually traveling. I've had situations where I really wanted to bring a candidate in, but I have off-site meeting scheduled for several weeks. More pressing things do come up. However, the fact that they're not keeping in touch with you says a lot about either their interest or professionalism. The only thing to be done is contact the employer.

Comment: You are free to disagree with the fluff. As I said, it was based on multiple personal experiences. One "memorable" instance was when I came across a "travelling" interviewer at a shopping mall. I realised what was going on, but nonetheless, since he did not see me, I called the company the next morning, and was told he still hasn't returned from his foreign trip.

Comment: Anyway, neither your personal anecdote nor mine can establish a general conclusion, but my point here really is there are several ways by which companies "communicate" rejection, and also several ways of putting people in hold. "Travelling" is just one of them, and OP should be aware of this possibility. Considering that over a week has passed *beyond* the two weeks, I am inclined to believe my interpretation is more likely to hold in the OP's case.